# How to transform JSON array response to xml array in esb wso2 using script mediator

Tags: json, xml, wso2, transform, esb

I am getting JSON array response in my ESB but I need to convert it to XML using script mediator.
The length of JSON array response is dynamic.I need to iterate through entire length of JSON array and convert it to xml. Please help.

Below is the JSON array response which I am getting now but length is not fixed.

```
    {
    "Results": [
        {
            "Id": 215766,
            "HostName": "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
            "IPAddress": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
            "ModelName": "HP COLOR LASERJET CP4520 SERIES",
            "SerialNumber": "JPDXG57J7Y",
            "FirmwareVersion": "07.160.6",
            "FirmwareDateCode": "2014-01-27T00:00:00Z",
            "LastContactTime": "2017-06-19T04:03:04Z",
            "TemplateSettings": {
                "ConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown",
                "LongLifeConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown"
            },
            "MacAddress": "xxx",
            "DeviceIntrinsicAttributeId": "SerialNumber",
            "ManufacturerName": "HP",
            "DeviceModelSupportTypeId": "Dat",
            "IsAmvDevice": false,
            "Guid": "3ff42b50-9d86-cf53-e053-0100007ffbe3",
            "MskuAttributeState": "Absent",
            "ActivationStatus": "Active",
            "GenuineHPCartridgeStatus": "GenuineHP",
            "HasGenuineHPCartridges": true
        },
        {
            "Id": 215757,
            "HostName": "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
            "IPAddress": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
            "ModelName": "HP COLOR LASERJET FLOW MFP M880",
            "SerialNumber": "CNCXG566XK",
            "FirmwareVersion": "2308209_000573",
            "FirmwareDateCode": "2016-08-20T00:00:00Z",
            "LastContactTime": "2017-06-19T04:02:22Z",
            "TemplateSettings": {
                "ConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown",
                "LongLifeConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown"
            },
            "MacAddress": "xxx",
            "DeviceIntrinsicAttributeId": "SerialNumber",
            "ManufacturerName": "HP",
            "DeviceModelSupportTypeId": "Dat",
            "IsAmvDevice": false,
            "Guid": "3bf42b50-c03b-863a-e053-0100007fad51",
            "MskuAttributeState": "Absent",
            "ActivationStatus": "Active",
            "GenuineHPCartridgeStatus": "CartridgeInBadState",
            "HasGenuineHPCartridges": true
        },
        {
            "Id": 215763,
            "HostName": null,
            "IPAddress": "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
            "ModelName": "HP COLOR LASERJET FLOW MFP M880",
            "SerialNumber": "CNDVGCS0LP",
            "FirmwareVersion": "2308209_000573",
            "FirmwareDateCode": "2016-08-20T00:00:00Z",
            "LastContactTime": "2017-06-19T04:03:11Z",
            "TemplateSettings": {
                "ConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown",
                "LongLifeConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown"
            },
            "MacAddress": "xxxx",
            "DeviceIntrinsicAttributeId": "SerialNumber",
            "ManufacturerName": "HP",
            "DeviceModelSupportTypeId": "Dat",
            "IsAmvDevice": false,
            "Guid": "3cf42b50-d977-d237-e053-0100007fae25",
            "MskuAttributeState": "Absent",
            "ActivationStatus": "Active",
            "GenuineHPCartridgeStatus": "GenuineHP",
            "HasGenuineHPCartridges": true
        },
        {
            "Id": 215762,
            "HostName": "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
            "IPAddress": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
            "ModelName": "HP LASERJET M4345 MFP",
            "SerialNumber": "CNCJ94000H",
            "FirmwareVersion": "48.306.1",
            "FirmwareDateCode": "2014-07-22T00:00:00Z",
            "LastContactTime": "2017-06-19T04:05:08Z",
            "TemplateSettings": {
                "ConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown",
                "LongLifeConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown"
            },
            "MacAddress": "xxx",
            "DeviceIntrinsicAttributeId": "SerialNumber",
            "ManufacturerName": "HP",
            "DeviceModelSupportTypeId": "Dat",
            "IsAmvDevice": false,
            "Guid": "3bf42b50-c13b-863a-e053-0100007fad51",
            "MskuAttributeState": "Absent",
            "ActivationStatus": "Active",
            "GenuineHPCartridgeStatus": "GenuineHP",
            "HasGenuineHPCartridges": true
        },
        {
            "Id": 215759,
            "HostName": "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
            "IPAddress": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
            "ModelName": "HP LASERJET M4345 MFP",
            "SerialNumber": "CNCJ98L01X",
            "FirmwareVersion": "48.306.1",
            "FirmwareDateCode": "2014-07-22T00:00:00Z",
            "LastContactTime": "2017-06-19T04:04:07Z",
            "TemplateSettings": {
                "ConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown",
                "LongLifeConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown"
            },
            "MacAddress": "xxx",
            "DeviceIntrinsicAttributeId": "SerialNumber",
            "ManufacturerName": "HP",
            "DeviceModelSupportTypeId": "Dat",
            "IsAmvDevice": false,
            "Guid": "3df42b50-a14a-a05b-e053-0100007f3f94",
            "MskuAttributeState": "Absent",
            "ActivationStatus": "Active",
            "GenuineHPCartridgeStatus": "NotSupported",
            "HasGenuineHPCartridges": true
        },
        {
            "Id": 224984,
            "HostName": "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
            "IPAddress": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
            "ModelName": "HP LASERJET M506",
            "SerialNumber": "PHCJQ00233",
            "FirmwareVersion": "2308209_000567",
            "FirmwareDateCode": "2016-08-20T00:00:00Z",
            "LastContactTime": "2017-06-16T04:09:27Z",
            "TemplateSettings": {
                "ConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown",
                "LongLifeConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown"
            },
            "MacAddress": "xxx",
            "DeviceIntrinsicAttributeId": "SerialNumber",
            "ManufacturerName": "HP",
            "DeviceModelSupportTypeId": "Dat",
            "IsAmvDevice": false,
            "Guid": "7aa4ca50-6303-7404-e053-0100007f7e65",
            "MskuAttributeState": "Absent",
            "ActivationStatus": "Active",
            "GenuineHPCartridgeStatus": "GenuineHP",
            "HasGenuineHPCartridges": true
        },
        {
            "Id": 215758,
            "HostName": "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
            "IPAddress": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
            "ModelName": "HP LASERJET M9040 MFP",
            "SerialNumber": "JPCXDDSBQH",
            "FirmwareVersion": "51.320.4",
            "FirmwareDateCode": "2017-01-24T00:00:00Z",
            "LastContactTime": "2017-06-19T04:02:03Z",
            "TemplateSettings": {
                "ConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown",
                "LongLifeConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown"
            },
            "MacAddress": "xxx",
            "DeviceIntrinsicAttributeId": "SerialNumber",
            "ManufacturerName": "HP",
            "DeviceModelSupportTypeId": "Dat",
            "IsAmvDevice": false,
            "Guid": "3cf42b50-d877-d237-e053-0100007fae25",
            "MskuAttributeState": "Absent",
            "ActivationStatus": "Active",
            "GenuineHPCartridgeStatus": "GenuineHP",
            "HasGenuineHPCartridges": true
        },
        {
            "Id": 215761,
            "HostName": null,
            "IPAddress": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
            "ModelName": "HP LASERJET P4515",
            "SerialNumber": "CNFY193829",
            "FirmwareVersion": "04.049.3",
            "FirmwareDateCode": "2009-09-25T00:00:00Z",
            "LastContactTime": "2017-06-14T03:55:39Z",
            "TemplateSettings": {
                "ConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown",
                "LongLifeConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown"
            },
            "MacAddress": "xxx",
            "DeviceIntrinsicAttributeId": "SerialNumber",
            "ManufacturerName": "HP",
            "DeviceModelSupportTypeId": "Dat",
            "IsAmvDevice": false,
            "Guid": "3ff42b50-9b86-cf53-e053-0100007ffbe3",
            "MskuAttributeState": "Absent",
            "ActivationStatus": "Active",
            "GenuineHPCartridgeStatus": "GenuineHP",
            "HasGenuineHPCartridges": true
        },
        {
            "Id": 240970,
            "HostName": "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
            "IPAddress": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
            "ModelName": "HP MFP S975DN",
            "SerialNumber": "5100008X00",
            "FirmwareVersion": "H1.07.t1.00",
            "FirmwareDateCode": null,
            "LastContactTime": "2017-06-14T05:58:08Z",
            "TemplateSettings": {
                "ConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown",
                "LongLifeConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown"
            },
            "MacAddress": "xxx",
            "DeviceIntrinsicAttributeId": "SerialNumber",
            "ManufacturerName": "HP",
            "DeviceModelSupportTypeId": "Dat",
            "IsAmvDevice": false,
            "Guid": "6c8b4351-1f83-b873-e053-0100007ffdc5",
            "MskuAttributeState": "Absent",
            "ActivationStatus": "Active",
            "GenuineHPCartridgeStatus": "NotAttempted",
            "HasGenuineHPCartridges": true
        },
        {
            "Id": 224986,
            "HostName": "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
            "IPAddress": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
            "ModelName": "HP PAGEWIDE PRO MFP 777HC",
            "SerialNumber": "MY73H5E00H",
            "FirmwareVersion": "LIMOFWMP2A006.1720B.00",
            "FirmwareDateCode": "2017-05-11T00:00:00Z",
            "LastContactTime": "2017-06-14T03:55:40Z",
            "TemplateSettings": {
                "ConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown",
                "LongLifeConsumablesStrategy": "Unknown"
            },
            "MacAddress": null,
            "DeviceIntrinsicAttributeId": "SerialNumber",
            "ManufacturerName": "HP",
            "DeviceModelSupportTypeId": "Dat",
            "IsAmvDevice": false,
            "Guid": "7aa4ca50-6503-7404-e053-0100007f7e65",
            "MskuAttributeState": "Absent",
            "ActivationStatus": "Active",
            "GenuineHPCartridgeStatus": "NotAttempted",
            "HasGenuineHPCartridges": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can use Jackson Plugin for this purpose,pretty easy and swift

Comment: I am doing transformation in ESB WSO2, so i will have to use script mediator.

Comment: ok... i just didn't knew about it

Comment: it's better if you use XSLT...1-transform from json to xml, 2-create a xslt transformation and use it inside esb.

Comment: Since, I am having json array so I will have to use script mediator.I have wriiten the script mediator code but now i am getting error as "The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator}
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined (<Unknown Source>#4) in <Unknown Source> at line number 4
 at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)"......Do you have any idea on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by writing below code.

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
               var   payload = mc.getPayloadJSON();
   var results = payload.Results;
    var response = <locations/>;
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
        var elem = results[i];
        response.locations += <jacdevice>
            <JACDeviceId>{elem.Id}</JACDeviceId>
            <Make>{elem.ManufacturerName}</Make>
            <Model>{elem.ModelName}</Model>
        </jacdevice>
    }
    mc.setPayloadXML(response);
                ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `messageType` property to out sequence, it should automatically convert the message to XML.

```
<outSequence>
    <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
    <send/>
</outSequence>
```

Answer (score -1):

My xml response should be like below

```
     <body>
   <p:jacdevice_batch_req xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      <!--1 or more occurrences-->
      <p:jacdevice xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:JACDeviceId xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">1</xs:JACDeviceId>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:Make xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">HP</xs:Make>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:Model xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">HP CM8060 Color MFP</xs:Model>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:SerialNumber xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">SerialNumberZ</xs:SerialNumber>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:IPv4 xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">IPV4z</xs:IPv4>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:MAC xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">MACZZ</xs:MAC>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:Hostname xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">HOST NAMEZ</xs:Hostname>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:FirstScanDate xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">2017-06-06 10:33:42.773</xs:FirstScanDate>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:LastScanDate xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">2017-06-06 10:33:42.773</xs:LastScanDate>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:Managed xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">1</xs:Managed>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:LastAttemptedContactTime xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">2017-06-06 10:33:42.773</xs:LastAttemptedContactTime>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:CredentialProfileStatus xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">aa</xs:CredentialProfileStatus>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:JACCredentialProfileId xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">1</xs:JACCredentialProfileId>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:FirmwareVersion xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">bb</xs:FirmwareVersion>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:FirmwareDateCode xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">cc</xs:FirmwareDateCode>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:JACAccountID xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">3113</xs:JACAccountID>
   </p:jacdevice>
    <p:jacdevice xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:JACDeviceId xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">9</xs:JACDeviceId>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:Make xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">HPjj</xs:Make>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:Model xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">HP CM8060 Color MFPjj</xs:Model>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:SerialNumber xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">SerialNumberkkZ</xs:SerialNumber>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:IPv4 xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">IPV4zjj</xs:IPv4>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:MAC xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">MACZZjj</xs:MAC>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:Hostname xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">HOST NAMEjjZ</xs:Hostname>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:FirstScanDate xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">2017-06-06 10:33:42.773</xs:FirstScanDate>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:LastScanDate xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">2017-06-06 10:33:42.773</xs:LastScanDate>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:Managed xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">1</xs:Managed>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:LastAttemptedContactTime xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">2017-06-06 10:33:42.773</xs:LastAttemptedContactTime>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:CredentialProfileStatus xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">aa</xs:CredentialProfileStatus>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:JACCredentialProfileId xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">1</xs:JACCredentialProfileId>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:FirmwareVersion xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">bb</xs:FirmwareVersion>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:FirmwareDateCode xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">cc</xs:FirmwareDateCode>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:JACAccountID xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">3113</xs:JACAccountID>
   </p:jacdevice>
   </p:jacdevice_batch_req>
</body>
```